# Collect all annotated class name in some scala object

Tags: scala, annotations

We have various class annotated with a scala macro annotation that add  a method to that class. At compile time, We want to add a list of these annotated class in some other object . So that we can access that list at run time. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a straight way to do this but what I did was pretty simple. Whenever my macro finds my annotated class, It writes the name of the class to a file in resources. At runtime, I made that file content available as a list through a new class method.

Comment: How did you achieve it?